# Example of sequence $\langle x_n\rangle$ with $x_n>0$ such that series $\sum x_n$ is convergent but $\langle nx_n\rangle$ is NOT a null sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, examples-counterexamples

Please provide an example of  sequence  $\langle x_n\rangle$ of positive terms such that series $\sum x_n$ is convergent but sequence $\langle nx_n\rangle$ is NOT  a null sequence.

I try hard but could not  find one such. Please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take $x_{n}=1/n$ if $n$ is a perfect square and $x_n=1/n^2$ otherwise. Then it is easy to see that $\sum x_n$ is convergent but $nx_n\not\to 0$ since $nx_n=1$ whenever $n$ is a perfect square.

Comment: how to prove that $\sum x_n $ converge in this case

Comment: @Eklavya $$\sum_{n\geq 1} x_n = \sum_{n \text{ is a square}} \frac{1}{n} + \sum_{n \text{ not a square}} \frac{1}{n^2} = \sum_{k\geq 1} \frac{1}{k^2} + \sum_{n \text{ not a square}} \frac{1}{n^2} \leq \sum_{k\geq 1} \frac{1}{k^2} + \sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{1}{n^2} = 2\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{1}{n^2}$$

Answer (score 6):

Start with any sequence $\langle y_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ of positive terms such that $\sum_{n\ge 1}y_n$ converges and replace $y_{n!}$ with $\frac1{n!}$ for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$.